# Recursive Type Representatives Using GADTs

Tags: haskell, gadt, recursive-type

I have the following GADT which can represent basic algebraic data types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

data Type :: * -> * where
  TUnit   :: Type ()
  TInt    :: Type Int
  (:+)    :: Type a -> Type b -> Type (Either a b)
  (:*)    :: Type a -> Type b -> Type (a, b)
  (:>)    :: Type a -> Type b -> Type (a -> b)
deriving instance Show (Type a)
```

I can use it along with the following GADT to create values with types available at runtime.

```
data Value where
  MkVal :: a -> Type a -> Value

someVal = MkVal (+) (TInt :> (TInt :> TInt))
```

This works well for non-recursive types, but I would also like to include other types like lists and trees without adding them in manually. A type constructor could be represented as a function `Type a -> Type b`, for example, `maybeConstr a = TUnit :+ a`. However, I cannot turn this into a recursive definition of Nat. Using `fix` doesn't work because the input and output types don't match up. Also, representing type constructors as functions seems like it could be problematic if I want to write an equality function for types. Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can represent a recursive type using a fixed point, by adding a constructor `TMu` to represent the recursive type μ*x*. *t*. This is a type that can be “unrolled” into the type *t* with *x* replaced with another copy of μ*x*. *t*: *t*[μ*x*. *t*/*x*]. For example, the list type could be written as L(*a*) = μ*x*. 1 + *a* × *x*; the type variable *x* represents the whole type L(*a*). (Technically this is the greatest fixed point ν, and μ is the least fixed point, but it’s common to use μ for both if we don’t care about the distinction.)

In order to use this, you will need some representation of type variables; a general-purpose way to represent this with your typed AST is to include the type of the “environment” among the type parameters of the GADT, and index into that environment with De Bruijn indices.

```
data Type :: [*] -> * -> * where
  TUnit   :: Type c ()
  TInt    :: Type c Int
  (:+)    :: Type c a -> Type c b -> Type c (Either a b)
  (:*)    :: Type c a -> Type c b -> Type c (a, b)
  (:>)    :: Type c a -> Type c b -> Type c (a -> b)

  TMu     :: Type (a ': c) b -> Type c (Mu a b)
  TVarZ   :: Type (a ': c) a
  TVarS   :: Type c a -> Type (x ': c) a
```

`TVarZ` references the variable at the top of the environment stack, and `TVarS` shifts the context to refer to other parts of the environment. If you will never need nested recursive types, you can get away without `TVarS`, and call `TVarZ` something like `TSelf` or `TRec` instead.

Formally, this makes each constructor of the GADT correspond to a *rule* of the type system that you’re representing: `Type γ α → Type γ β → Type γ (α × β)` corresponds directly to the sequent (Γ ⊢ α) ∧ (Γ ⊢ β) ⇒ (Γ ⊢ α × β).

If you want to be able to represent type constructors within `Type`, the process is similar: `Maybe a` ≅ 1 + *a* can also be thought of as `Maybe` ≅ ∀*a*. 1 + *a*, where ∀ here is much like λ at the term level. So you would need to add `TForall` and `TApp` constructors to `Type`, and use the `TVar` constructors to refer to the variables they bind.

This raises two issues. First, you need to consider *kinds* now, too, although you don’t need to represent them explicitly if your type parameters are all basic types (i.e. not type constructors). Second, you’re currently indexing the GADT with Haskell types directly, but you will run into issues using `TForall :: Type (a ': c) b -> Type c (forall a. b)` directly; a typical solution is to create a basic “untyped” version of your AST type:

```
data UType where
  UTUnit   :: UType
  UTInt    :: UType
  UTSum    :: UType -> UType -> UType
  UTProd   :: UType -> UType -> UType
  UTFun    :: UType -> UType -> UType
```

Then `data Type :: * -> *` becomes `data Type :: UType -> *`, using `DataKinds`:

```
data Type :: * -> * where
  TUnit   :: Type 'UTUnit
  TInt    :: Type 'UTInt
  (:+)    :: Type a -> Type b -> Type ('UTSum a b)
  (:*)    :: Type a -> Type b -> Type ('UTProd a b)
  (:>)    :: Type a -> Type b -> Type ('UTFun a b)
```

(And this is basically the “singleton” form of `UType`.)

You would then extend this for the above cases, and have an interpretation to and from Haskell types.

The De Bruijn representation makes it easy to derive equality on `Type`s, but there are several possible representations of variable binding here, such as variable names, “locally nameless”, “higher-order abstract syntax” (HOAS), or using point-free type combinators only.

Comment: This is very helpful, but I have a few followup questions. In the types of `(:+) `, `(:*) `, and `(:>) `, you have that the inputs have the same contexts so you can’t combine, for example, TInt and TVarZ. Would you need some type leve concatenation for this? Second, how exactly is `Mu a b ` defined? I tried adapting the definition `Mu f = Mu (forall r. (f r -> r) -> r ` without much luck since in our case `b ` is not a type constructor.

Comment: @vigenary: Ah yeah, the empty context `'[]` should have been a polymorphic `c` there, I was making it linear for no reason. But you’re right, if you want to combine multiple contexts you would need e.g. `type family (++) :: [k] -> [k] -> [k]`. I think I overcomplicated `TMu`, which should be more like `TMu :: Type (a ': c) a -> Type c a` (cf. the type of `fix :: (a -> a) -> a`). `a` is the whole type here, so it’s a base type, not a constructor. Pretty sure I’ve seen this explained in a paper…will try to find a reference or write a more complete example when I have a moment.